# Telerik Blazor question Disabling Grid Update button on Popup Edit

Tags: blazor, grid, telerik, blazor-server-side, telerik-grid

I want to make the update button on the Edit Grid popup window inactive. This is to prevent users from accidentally clicking the update button twice.

I have added the popup window picture showing update button.

```
 <GridSettings>
                <GridPopupEditSettings Width="40vw"
                                       Height="auto"
                                       Title="@PopupTitle"
                                       Class="custom-popup">
                </GridPopupEditSettings>
                <GridPopupEditFormSettings Orientation="@FormOrientation.Horizontal"
                                           ButtonsLayout="FormButtonsLayout.Stretch"
                                           Columns="1">
                </GridPopupEditFormSettings>
            </GridSettings>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet with your code at https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/